# Why does case matching introduce bias?

Tags: causality, matching, confounding

I was reading the paper Biases Introduced by Choosing Controls to Match Risk Factors of Cases in Biomarker Research by Pepe et al. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3464972/  where she argues that matching by cases will produce bias in estimating the added predictive value of a biomarker to the set of confounds. I.e., a biomarker might look good in a matched sample while providing only a little additional benefit in the original sample. This might even lead to a situation where the added value of a biomarker A is higher than B in the original sample but lower in the matched sample, thus leading to a selection of a worse biomarker.

[image]

My problem is that I do not understand the argument and why that is. I tried to reproduce some of the figures from the paper but wasn't able to do so. Can someone explain this problem to me, and when matching leads to wrong results?